# Add class to parent div when child div is "display: block" and remove when "display: none"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I have a tabs setup, and I'm looking to accomplish the following:

I want child divs with class `fifty` to add class `flex` to their parent div `DTE_Form_Content` when their style is `display: block`, and remove class `flex` when their style is `display: none`.

The structure is like this:

```
<div class="DTE_Form_Content">
    <div class="DTE_Field_Name_ps-ceilings_amt" style="display: none">
    <div class="DTE_Field_Name_app-co-ds fifty" style="display: block">
</div>
```

This would allow me to change the format of the child div's layout. How could I accomplish this? What I was thinking may work:

```
if ( $('div.fifty').css('style="display: block"') ) {
  $('div.DTE_Form_Content').addClass('flex');
} else {
  $('div.DTE_Form_Content').removeClass('flex');
}
```

EDIT: This is not a duplicate question. My question pertains to children containing a specific class, whereas the marked duplicate does not.

Comment: what did you try so far? share your code.

Comment: Added code I thought may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $dte = $('.DTE_Form_Content');

$('.fifty').is(':visible') ? $dte.addClass('flex') : $dte.removeClass('flex')
```

You could try this solution, using a ternary also adds an element of cleanliness IMO. If this works for you consider accepting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($("div.fifty").css("display")=="block")
{
 $("div.DTE_Form_Content").addClass("flex");
}
else
{
 $("div.DTE_Form_Content").removeClass("flex");
}
```